# why readOGR() is not reading projection information from .spj - r

Tags: r, shapefile, map-projections, rgdal

I successfully import a polygon shapefile with readOGR, however the information in the .prj file is not being imported.

> test
>   class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
>   nfeatures   : 19407 
>   extent      : 35551.4, 1585917, 6318047, 9408727  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : NA
>
> summary(test)
>   Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
>   Coordinates:
>           min     max
>   x   35551.4 1585917
>   y 6318047.3 9408727
>   Is projected: NA 
>   proj4string : [NA]

the projection should be utm21n complex zone

Comment: @SlowLearner: I see no similar post for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issues was the rgdal version.

> Edzer: When I replace the .prj file of an arbitrary shapefile with
>   these  contents, it gets read well. Have you tried with current R
>   (3.2.4) and  rgdal (1.1.7)?
>   Vinh_Nguyen: Thanks Edzer, upgrading
>   rgdal to 1.1.8 works.  Consider this issue close.

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/readOGR-not-reading-in-prj-file-td7589717.html